# Wired connection keeps on dropping

Tags: networking, internet

I know there are some similar questions over here but none of them actually works. I am experiencing a lot of problems in connecting to the internet through a wired connection on Ubuntu. The connection gets lost in middle of work and does not work thereafter. earlier restarting the network service worked for a bit but now nothing of it works. Please need help badly. If you need some more info please let me know in comments section I will update the question. Right now I am not sure what all info to include.

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 15
   serial: ac:e2:d3:67:bf:8f
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.10.14.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4104000-b4104fff memory:b4100000-b4103fff
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @heynnema Here..updated. Turns out when I create a new wired profile, with ipv6 disabled the network works though the drops are still there. I need to reset the networks through the terminal and it starts to work after that.

Comment: Please describe your cabling, from the computer port, to the router/modem. Your connection is showing up as 100Mb, but that's on a 1Gb interface. You may have a cabling/hub/switch/router/modem problem, or a problem with the r8169 driver (for which there is a fix).

Comment: @heynnema Actually I am connected to my institute's LAN connection. I am not sure what details you need.

Comment: Try a different ethernet cable, or try using a different wall plate port. Use `sudo lshw -C network` to check for connection "size", should = "capacity".

Comment: @heynnema Okk.. I will try it out.Thanks